# Date using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

**Edit**: Previously only HTML was there but in new update even Javascript works but purely Javascript ... I can't add HTML there...

I am working on a WordPress site, I need to display an image dynamically in a site. Image source will be like:

```
site.com/files/year/month/date/img1.jpg
```

But in my theme I can only input either HTML or JS there... generally if it is a static site then we can only use that image but my image gets updated daily... i.e.

- today it will be site.com/files/2015/4/13/img1.jpg
- tomorrow it will be site.com/files/2015/4/14/img1.jpg

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. 

If you are using wordpress you have the ability to use PHP... as well as javascript. You could dynamically change images with both of those languages. What makes you think you can only use HTML. Do you have FTP access, etc.

Comment: If you want it to be done with only html, then why do you put `javascript` as tagged.

Comment: It can't be done with HTML.  You could either use javascript or just replace the existing image rather than adding a new one (although the previous image will get cached by browsers for a while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image = document.getElementById('yourImagesId');
var date = new Date();
var url = 'site.com/files/' + date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() +1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/img1.jpg';
image.setAttribute('src',url);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is Hyper-Text **Markup Language**.  It isn't "code" in the sense that it doesn't have any logic or power.  It exists to literally markup your copy; that is, it's primary use is to define the layout of the content of your page.

To do anything dynamic, you need an actual coding language that can perform actual logic functions, so you'll have to utilize JavaScript (or PHP, as you're in Wordpress).

I'd be lying if I said I had experience in Wordpress's environment, but I'd imagine that googling "wordpress dynamic image path plugin" would possibly yield some tangible results.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean only with HTML, as for Javascript:

```
var currDate = new Date();
var url = "site.com/files/" + currDate.getFullYear() + "/"
    + (currDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currDate.getDate() 
    + "/" + imageName + "." + imageFormat;
```

getMonth will get the month as a number from 0 to 11 so you add 1 if needed to have it as 1 ~ 12.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pu4dp7p7/)

Be aware that JS takes the date and time from the client.